# Elections notification?

Tags: bug, election

I just got a message in my SE inbox telling me I needed to vote in the SP:SE moderator elections... but I don't see that actually going on and now the message has disappeared?! I'm more than a little confused. Was this a fluke or am I going blind?

Comment: Strange indead!

Comment: Powered by SharePoint? ;)

Comment: Nooooo SharePoint doesn't have any flaws in it at all! ;)

Comment: Next time you see it, don't forget to take a screenshot :P !

Comment: Same happened to me @thanby - I will watch closely next year to see if it happens again.